# Linker cannot find existing library on Eclipse C on OSX

Tags: c, eclipse, macos

I have a custom librar (.a file) that I want to add to my C project in eclipse.
I have tried to add it in `Project Preferences -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Libraries`. This location automatically shows up in `Project Preferences -> C/C++ Build -> Setting -> Tools Settings -> MacOS X C Linker -> Libraries`

When I build my project I get the following error in the build console:

```
Building target: TestOfLibrary
Invoking: MacOS X C Linker
gcc  -o "TestOfLibrary"  ./src/TestOfLibrary.o   -l"/Users/me/workspaces/test/libs/mylib.a"
ld: library not found for -l/Users/me/workspaces/test/libs/mylib.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [TestOfLibrary] Error 1
```

The path to the library is correct, without typos, and the files exists.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

@Tobber

On the gcc command options you may want to add the *Library Search Path* flag. Assuming that you're linking a static library (mylib.a) the following would be the command/flags you want to run:

> **gcc TestOfLibrary.c -L/Users/me/workspaces/test/libs -lmylib**
>
> The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any  > that you specify with -L.
>
> Normally the files found this way are library files—archive files whose members > are object files.

Further reference: [Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options).

Being said, this is my Eclipse configuration I'd use to set it up accordingly:

C/C++ Build/Settings: http://www.screencast.com/t/vJLsjzGVJ8N

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not have the setup anymore, so I can't test your solution. If there is anybody else out there, that can confirm this fix, please comment here, and I'll accept the answer.